# Does reshape2 have casetovars equivalent?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidy

I have: data table:

| Id | Time | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | T1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
|  | T2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
|  | T3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |

Basically, I have data in three waves (T1, T2) etc. I need to make it a wide format so it looks like this:

| id | v1T1 | v2T1 | v3T1 | v1T2 | v2T2 | v3T2 | v1T3 | V2T3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

I have tried the following code:

```
data %>%
     group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(id=paste0("id", row_number())) %>%
     spread(id, v1, v2, v3)
```

What am I missing? I know how to do this with casetovars in SPSS, but I can't duplicate it in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pivot_wider` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = Time, values_from = v1:v3)

#     Id v1_T1 v1_T2 v1_T3 v2_T1 v2_T2 v2_T3 v3_T1 v3_T2 v3_T3
#  <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     2     3     1     1     1     3     2     2     3
```

Or using `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), Id~Time, value.var = c('v1', 'v2', 'v3'))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Id = c(1, 1, 1), Time = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), v1 = c(2L, 
3L, 1L), v2 = c(1L, 1L, 3L), v3 = c(2L, 2L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question title mentions "reshape2", the function you'd be looking for in that package is `recast`. The `recast` function is basically a `melt` followed by a `dcast`, which is required in `reshape2::dcast` to cast multiple value variables (but not in `data.table::dcast`, which can accept a vector of value variables, as demonstrated in [Ronak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65333643/1270695)).

Here's what it looks like:

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, ... ~ variable + Time, id.var=1:2)
##   Id v1_T1 v1_T2 v1_T3 v2_T1 v2_T2 v2_T3 v3_T1 v3_T2 v3_T3
## 1  1     2     3     1     1     1     3     2     2     3
```

For reference, you can also do this with `reshape` from base R:

```
reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "Id", timevar = "Time")
##   Id v1.T1 v2.T1 v3.T1 v1.T2 v2.T2 v3.T2 v1.T3 v2.T3 v3.T3
## 1  1     2     1     2     3     1     2     1     3     3
```

That said, many people find `reshape` very hard to learn, and while the "reshape2" package will be maintained, it's not being actively developed. Thus, while you can expect that things won't break, new features aren't going to be added to it. For that, you'll have to look at the "data.table" implementation or start using "tidyr" or other alternatives.